# Create Unique Groups Based On Consecutive Observations

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am looking for a data.table solution for the following problem.

Suppose that I have the following data.table:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT <- data.table(year = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020),
                 store = c(1,2,2,2,1),
                 name = c("J", "J", "J", "J", "J"),
                 begin = c("2016-01-01", "2017-10-22", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-26"),
                 end = c("2017-02-19", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2020-01-26", "2020-12-31"))
                 

DT[, `:=`(begin = ymd(begin),
          end = ymd(end))]
```

I would like to summarize the data.table such that I have the beginning and end dates for each person (indicated by the variable name) at each store. So I would like a data.table that looks like:

```
 store   name      begin        end
   <num> <char>     <Date>     <Date>
1:     1      J 2016-01-01 2017-02-19
2:     1      J 2020-01-26 2020-12-31
3:     2      J 2017-10-22 2020-01-26
```

The issue with the following command:

```
DT_sum <- DT[, .(begin = min(begin),
                 end = max(end)), by =.(store, name)]
```

is that it does not account for the fact that "J" leaves the store, and returns later. Thus, the interval is too large. I am wondering if there was a concise data.table way of handling this problem, where a person can return to a single store multiple times throughout their tenure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. There is a one-liner that does this:

```
DT[, store_grp := rleid(store, name, prefix = NULL)]
```

which gives us:

```
  year store   name      begin        end store_grp
   <num> <num> <char>     <Date>     <Date>     <int>
1:  2016     1      J 2016-01-01 2017-02-19         1
2:  2017     2      J 2017-10-22 2017-12-31         2
3:  2018     2      J 2018-01-01 2018-12-31         2
4:  2019     2      J 2019-01-01 2020-01-26         2
5:  2020     1      J 2020-01-26 2020-12-31         3
```